# Compute a Matrix from a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Define the linear map $A: \mathcal{P}_2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by the formula $$Ap = \left (\int_0^1p(t)dt,\int_0^2p(t)dt,\int_0^3p(t)dt \right) = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$$

a)Compute the matrix of A in the basis 1,t,t^2 in $\mathcal{P}_2$ and the usual basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$

b)Can you recover $p(t)$ from $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, and if yes, how?

c)Compute $A^{-1}$ if it exists.  Is this computation legitimate even though A maps one vector space into a different vector space?

What I think so far:

a)I honestly have no clue how to approach this.

b) I want to say no, as taking the integrals only gives you p(t) from 0 to 3.

c) Again, I honestly have no clue how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) If you have a linear map $L:V\to W$ and you have basis $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ for $V$ and $\{w_1,\ldots, w_m\}$ for $W$, then the matrix associated to $L$ in these two basis is
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\\vdots& & \vdots\\ a_{m1}&\cdots& a_{mn}\end{pmatrix}$$
where
$$L(v_j)=\sum a_{ij}w_i$$
i.e. the $j$-th column is made by the coefficients of the image of $v_j$ with respect to the basis $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^m$.

In your case, for example, if $p(t)=1$, $Ap=(1,2,3)=1e_1+2e_2+3e_3$, so the first *column* is $(1,2,3)$ … I think you now know how to find the other two columns. Call the matrix $M$.

b) Write $p(t)=at^2+bt+c$, then 
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=M\cdot \begin{pmatrix}c\\b\\a\end{pmatrix}$$
given that you now know the explicit form of $M$, can't you find $a$, $b$, $c$ in terms of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, solving the linear system?

c) Can you invert the matrix $M$? If yes, the application given by $M^{-1}$ with respect to the basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and ${1,t,t^2}$ in the two given vector spaces is the inverse of $A$.
I don't understand the question about $A$ being defined between different vector spaces… Unless they are really asking you to calculate matrix of the inverse of $A$ by means of inverting $M$; this works (and it is what I just suggested you doing) because once we pick a basis, we give an isomorphism of our vector space with some $\mathbb{R}^n$, where linear maps are exactly matrices and inverses of linear maps are found by inverting them as matrices.